# How do I hide a directory even if the show hidden files is set?

Tags: c#, attributes, hidden-files

I'm looking to hide directories and unhide them. I want the directories and everything in them to be hidden even if the user sets the Hidden files and folders option to Show hidden files, folders, and drives. Right now i'm using code like this:

```
File.SetAttributes(@"C:\Special", File.GetAttributes(@"C:\Special") |
                            (FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden));
```

I thought adding a system attribute would give it that extra hide. The problem I'm getting is the file is hidden and I'm still able to see it if I set my laptop to Show hidden files, folders, or drives. I'm using Windows 10. Could someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: This is more related to the OS than C#, and I know of no way to accomplish what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible or it would be severely exploited.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain why you need an hidden folder and how do you plan to use it, we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: a friend has a desktop and is sharing it with someone else. He wants to leave his file on the computer but make sure they are hidden from the other person.

Comment: Create another user account?  Zip the files with a password?  The details of the problem are a little indistinct.